# NPM install with proxy configuration error

Tags: npm

1. I am trying to install vue...

   C:\Users\jfalcon\Desktop\VUE>npm create vue@latest
2. But I get this error

> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
> npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vue
>  failed, reason:
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
> C:\Users\jfalcon\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-03T16_04_21_596Z-debug-0.log

3. I am currently behind a proxy but I already configured the variables and now I get this other error...

> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\jfalcon\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-03T15_56_28_081Z-debug-0.log

4. It happens with any npm command, so it's a configuration problem

Could someone help me? What am I not seeing?

Comment: When you open your log files --> `2023-11-03T16_04_21_596Z-debug-0.log` what does it say?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet or you are behind a proxy/VPN ?

Comment: in the log file the same error description and yes i am behind a proxy